# HTML/Javascript - Button onClick calling function with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an online store, I have an button which calls a function called `purchase()`, but in Javascript this function has `purchase(name, amount)`. So, you can put name easily, in the onclick function `onclick="purchase('milk')`, but my problem is  how I could put the amount? Amount is being chosen from the `<select>` element.

I created somekind of JSFiddle as well, so you can take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/w2bk9hw8/

Comment: I posted a jQuery answer if you have multiple buttons on the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you could do this;

```
 <button class="button" onclick="payment('milk', $('select').val())">$1.85</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but if I have multiple buttons there with choosing the amount?

Comment: @AleksKpur-  I dont understand what you asking.  Do you mean multiple `select` fields or submit buttons.  If you have more than one button you can do the same. If you have multiple `select` than change `$('select')` to the id of the `select` field. ex: `$('#myselect1')`.

Answer (score 1):

A JQuery less solution could be:

```
<div id="milkItem" class="shopping-item">
    <div class="name">Milk</div>
    <div class="item-image"></div>
    <div class="item-descriptor">Description of your item</div>

    <select class="qtySelector">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <button
         onclick="payment(document.getElementById('milkItem').getElementsByClassName('name')[0], 
         document.getElementById('milkItem').getElementsByClassName('qtySelector')[0].value)">
               Add to cart
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing weird on that. You'll just have to write the funcion and invoke it.

```js
function purchase(product){
      var select = document.querySelector("select#id");
      alert('You have ordered '+select.value+' unit(s) of ' + product);
    }
```

```html
  <select id="id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="purchase('milk')">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function payment(name, amount) {
        console.log(amount,name);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="quantity">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<button class="button" onclick="payment('milk', $('#quantity').val())">$1.85</button>
```

And find the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2bk9hw8/12/)

Please mark this if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

this should work(pure javascript):

```
<select id="amount">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
<button class="button" onclick="order('milk', getAmount)">$1.85</button>

<script>
  function order(name, amount) {
    alert(name);
    alert(getAmount());
  }

    function getAmount(){
    return document.getElementById('amount').value
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your select an id, and then it's very simple:

```html
<select id="target-select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
<button class="button" onclick="payment('milk', document.getElementById('target-select').value)">$1.85</button>

<script>
  function payment(name, amount) {
    alert(name);
    alert(amount);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering both the answers at the time of posting are in Jquery , i'm providing one in JS.

**Providing values to each option**

I've added values to the selects as they are necessary to get which number is allocated to each select option.

```
  <option value="2">2</option>
```

**Getting the value of the selected option**

To get the value of the select button, you can access the button using document.getElementById('sel') and use the .value operator to get the selected option.

```
document.getElementById('sel').value)
```

You can find the snippet below.

```js
 function order(name, amount) {
    alert(name);
    alert(amount);
  }
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<button class="button" onclick="order('milk',document.getElementById('sel').value)">$1.85</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```js
$('#myselect').on('click', function(){
var value  = $('#myselect option:selected').val();
$('button').html(value +'$');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
<button class="button">$1.85</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For if you have multiple buttons on the page...

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    payment('milk', $(this).attr("value"));
});
```